# What is wrong in my reputation calculation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, rep-recalc

See my reputation history first:

[image]

So, the reputation calculation is:

```
Cause                    Reputation Increase
-------------------      -------------------
1. Basic reputation                        1
2. Sep 9                                 100
3. Oct 5                                   2
4. Oct 6                                   2
5. Nov 18                                 10
6. Today                                  58
--------------------------------------------
Total                                    173
```

But my reputation is showing 175. And always it shows two more than what I could conclude from the calculation.

Could you help me to understand the metter?

You could find my reputation history [here](https://superuser.com/users/495344/manetsus?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Looks like the downvote here was reversed, and that isn't reflected in the events for some reason.  Not sure if its a bug.

Comment: Most probably its a bug. Should I retag with `bug`?

Comment: @manetsus - No;  It was my vote that was reversed;  Your total reputation gains or decrease for the day have not been calculated yet.

Comment: @Ramhound So, if it is not a bug, then when it would be calculated?

Comment: It happens daily

Comment: Oh, It is fixed now, Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Journeyman Geek - it is unbelievable to what level of detail you would go to - to resolve such a question... Excellent work